# Actionscript 3 addChild problems

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

The error messages from FlashDevelop are rather difficult to translate.

I'm using addChild in several situations, generally with no problems.  However, every once in a while I get:

Error: Call to a possibly undefined method addChild.

However, the exact same code works in other classes, and I am importing exactly the same files.  Obviously addChild is not an undefined method!  Here's the code- works in one module, doesn't work in another.

```
public var artist:Loader;
public var artistName:Loader;

public function SceneTJ():void {
    artistName = new Loader();
    artistName.load(new URLRequest("images/artistname.jpg"));
    artist = new Loader();
    artist.load(new URLRequest("images/artist.jpg"));
    artistName.x = artistName.y = 0;
    artist.x = 0;
    artist.y = 0;

    addChild(artist);
    addChild(artistName);
}
```

Comment: If somebody knows how to get the code so it looks right here, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  Like a dummy, I forgot to add "extends Sprite" after the class declaration.